# Heard of a framework/app which only returns exactly what you need from the database?

Tags: javascript, json, database, frameworks

I think I have read about some kind of framework or application with which, if I remember correctly, I could request data and only get what I needed in return.

I have searched the web for hours, but I am not really a great programmer and do not know exactly what I am looking for, can anyone help me with a name? Have you heard of something like this before? (I thought maybe it was made by Google?)

**Functionality:**

I think it worked by sending some kind of json request to the server where you said exactly what you needed. By being exact I would limit the size of the response and save bandwith, memory usage etc. Usually I would just request the whole "persons" object, but with this framework I think the approach was something like this:

Say the database contains something like this:

```
{
    "persons": {
        "John": {
            "age": 31,
            "city": "New York",
            <lots of other properties>
        },

        "Doe": {
            "age": 30,
            "city": "Washington DC",
            <lots of other properties>
        }
    }
}
```

I think I could request **only** the data I needed by sending a json request with empty properties; something like this:

```
{
    "persons": {
        "John": {
            "city": ""
        },

        "Doe": {
            "city": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Which would return John and Does cities like this:

```
{
    "persons": {
        "John": {
            "city": "New York"
        },

        "Doe": {
            "city": "Washington DC"
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know of such a framework or application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, Facebook launched a thing called [GraphQL](http://graphql.org/learn/) some time ago.

Comment: Are you freekin kidding with me!? You are faaast and very correct! Awesome, man, THANK YOU! This have been bugging for days... Thank you, and have a nice day further.

Comment: @user2267097 no problem, man :) Please mark this answer as correct when SO let you. Thanks and have a nice day :)

Comment: Can not mark it as correct the first 10 minutes... But thanks for the heads up :) @jimmyweb